# How to/Can I refactor duplicate code with injected interface into an abstract class?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

My application has a lot of "section" pages that contain some common functions.

```
public bool HasSection(Guid id)
{
    var entity = _repository.Find(id);
    var hasSection = entity != null;
    return hasSection;
}

public void Finalize(Guid id)
{
    _repository.UpdateStatus(id, SectionStatus.Completed);
    _repository.Save();
}
```

That `_repository` above, is injected from a `IRepository<T>`.

```
private readonly IRepository<SomeDomainModel> _repository;
public SomeModelWorkerServices(IRepository<SomeDomainModel> repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}

public void Update(SomeInputModel model)
{
    var entity = Mapper.Map<SomeDomainModel>(model);

    _repository.Update(entity);
    _repository.Save();
}
```

Since the methods `HasSection` and `Finalize` are the same in all sections, I think I could refactor the duplicated code into an abstract  class.

The interface of the abstract class:

```
public interface ISectionWorkerServices<T>
{
    bool HasSection(Guid id);
    void Finalize(Guid id, SectionStatus status);
    ... some other methods to be overriden in each inherated class.
    void Update(T model);
}
```

where T is supposed to be a base model for all my section input models.

In the implementation, I find it difficult to inject the `_repository`.

```
public abstract class SectionWorkerServices<T> : ISectionWorkerServices<T> where T :SectionInputModelBase
{
    private readonly IRepository<TDomainModel> _repository; // a T for its domain model

    protected SectionWorkerServices(IRepository<TDomainModel> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public bool HasSection(Guid id)
    {
        var entity = _repository.Find(id);
        var hasSection = entity != null;
        if (hasSection) _repository.Detach(entity);
        return hasSection;
    }
    ....
    public abstract void Update(T  model, SectionStatus status);
}
```

In the `SectionWorkerServices`, I want to use `T` as the `InputModel` for each implementation. But in the constructor of this `SectionWorkerServices` I need to inject `T`'s corresponding domain model repository.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: so the concrete services know what repository to use? the repositiories are generic themselves and use the same generic type of base SectionInputModelBase?

Comment: That is my problem. Can I inject a `TDomain` at the abstract class? Or just, what is the best way to refactor that duplicated code?

Comment: if you got the same constraints on the generic type you can just have a IRepository<T> ... if that is different you could try implementing it with 2 generic types... the other thing is you could do is provide an instance of the repository from the derived class (see template method design pattern or more precise factory method)

Comment: the template method pattern is also nice to encapsulate common behaviour... reference: http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class SectionWorkerServices<T> : ISectionWorkerServices<T> where T :SectionInputModelBase
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> _repository; // a T for its domain model

    protected SectionWorkerServices()
    {
        _repository = CreateRepository();
    }

    public bool HasSection(Guid id)
    {
        var entity = _repository.Find(id);
        var hasSection = entity != null;
        if (hasSection) _repository.Detach(entity);
        return hasSection;
    }
    ....
    public abstract void Update(T  model, SectionStatus status);

    //Factory Method
    protected abstract IRepository<T> CreateRepository();
}
```

Or with 2 generic types:

```
public abstract class SectionWorkerServices<T,TDomainModel> : ISectionWorkerServices<T> where T :SectionInputModelBase
{
    private readonly IRepository<TDomainModel> _repository;

    protected SectionWorkerServices()
    {
        _repository = CreateRepository();
    }

    public bool HasSection(Guid id)
    {
        var entity = _repository.Find(id);
        var hasSection = entity != null;
        if (hasSection) _repository.Detach(entity);
        return hasSection;
    }
    ....
    public abstract void Update(T  model, SectionStatus status);

    //Factory Method
    protected abstract IRepository<TDomainModel> CreateRepository();
}
```

**Edit**

```
public abstract class SectionWorkerServices<T> : ISectionWorkerServices<T> where T :SectionInputModelBase
{
    protected SectionWorkerServices()
    {

    }

    public bool HasSection(Guid id)
    {
        var entity = Repository.Find(id);
        var hasSection = entity != null;
        if (hasSection) Repository.Detach(entity);
        return hasSection;
    }
    ....
    public abstract void Update(T  model, SectionStatus status);

    protected abstract IRepository<T> Repository { get; }
}
```

And in the concrete services

```
public ConcreteSectionWorkerService : SectionWorker<SomeDomainModel>
{
    protected override IRepository<SomeDomainModel> Repository { get; private set; }

    public ConcreteSectionWorkerService()
    {
        Repository = new WhatEverRepository(); //carefull you have to set this...
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what is the use of `CreateRepository()`?

Comment: @Blaise It supposed to create the instance of the concrete repository... otherwise you need to call :base(new Whateverrepository()) on the constructor of the concrete classes ... in my opinion not really clean... that's only an opinion though =)

Comment: @Blaise check the other design patterns too, found by the link under your question... they make life a lot easier

Comment: As for the `CreateRepository()` method called in the constructor, ReSharper says "Virtual member call in constructor".

Comment: @Blaise Alternative you can make an abstract property with only a getter to get the repository from the concrete classes...